# Decrypt encrypted data from SQL Server by PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, encryption

My problem is that I would like to decrypt encrypted data from my SQL Server using PHP but I am not sure how to do this

SQL File

```
CREATE DATABASE testen
go

USE testen
go

CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Ma INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Sensitive VARBINARY(256)
)

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY MySymmetricKey
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256_
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'MyPassword';

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY MySymmetricKey DECRYPTION  BY PASSWORD = 'MyPassword'

-- Encrypt the data and store it in the database

INSERT INTO MyTable (Sensitive)

VALUES (EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('MySymmetricKey'), 'Sensitive Data'));
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

PHP

```
<?php
    // Connect to the SQL Server database
    $serverName = "LAPTOP-7A7MOGOK\MSSQLSERVER2";
    $connectionInfo = array("Database" => "testen", "UID" => "sa", "PWD" => "04052002");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    // Retrieve the encrypted data from the database
    
    $query = "SELECT Sensitive 
    FROM MyTable";
    $result = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query);
    sqlsrv_execute($result);
    // Decrypt the data using the symmetric key
    
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $encryptedData = $row['Sensitive'];
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
        $decryptedData = openssl_decrypt($encryptedData, 'AES-256-gcm', 'MySymmetricKey', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        var_dump($decryptedData);
    }
    // Close the database connection
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);
    sqlsrv_close($conn);

    ?>
```

It return bool(false). I want to decrypt encrypted data of sql server in client.

Comment: It seems that you do already have some code that you've tried, which is a great start; but you don't explain why you still need our help - what happens when you run the code shown? Can you [edit] to include a [mre] with input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: Are you really want to use `openssl_decrypt()` instead of `SELECT DecryptByKey(Sensitive) FROM ... `?

Comment: It might help to think about what encryption is *preventing* attackers from doing - it shouldn't be possible for me to take the encrypted data from your database, and run some PHP code to get the original data back, without knowing your secret keys and passwords. 'MySymmetricKey' isn't the actual secret key, it's the name of where it's stored in your database. Similarly, the point of the "IV" is that it's chosen at random when *encrypting* the data to make the result unpredictable, but to *decrypt* it you need to know what was chosen, not generate a *new* random value.